# Get the value between options

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the value between options without using the value:

```
<select name="get" class="get" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Val1</option>
<option value="2">Val2</option>
<option value="3">Val3</option>
</select>
```

I would like to get the result: Val1 and not 1

NB: It might be multiple selection with comma between them

Val1, Val3

Thanks in advance

Comment: How and when? Try `$(...).text()`

Comment: `$('.get option:selected').text();`

Comment: Oh thanks, awesome, the reason is to display that in a text and send values into another page using form tag

Comment: if it is a multiple selection, and I would like to use comma between them, how can I proceed that?

Comment: Question edited above